# insert a single character

Tags: commands, characters

**My goal** Write code in my `init.el` file so that from now on, `M-v` will just print the BELL character (character number 27 in hexadecimal) instead of scrolling down as it does by default.

**My failed attempts :**

Attempt 1: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-v") (quote ("'")))`

This gives no error message but `M-v` just says `command undefined` and does not print the character.

Attempt 2 : `(global-set-key (kbd "M-v") (insert-char("BELL")))`

Produces the following error message :

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘.emacs.d/init.el’: 
Invalid function: BELL
```

Attempt 3 : `(global-set-key (kbd "M-v") (insert-char(#x27)))`

Produces the following error message:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘.emacs.d/init.el’:
Invalid function: 39
```

Comment: #x27 is an apostrophe, I guess you mean 7 (the ASCII "bell" character). There is also #x1F514 for the "bell emoji" . Or if you actually want the sound, see [(elisp) Beeping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Beeping.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keybindings need to refer to commands, which means you need to wrap
your code in a `lambda` form. Also this is Lisp, so you don't need to
surround the arguments to a function in parentheses. That all adds up
to:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-v") (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (insert-char #x27)))
```

Comment: Just checked that it works, thank you !